# How do you use the stellar quickstart without docker?

Tags: horizon, docker, new-developer, developersguide

It says "The easiest way to install Horizon is by using stellar/quickstart docker image."

But I can't run the "docker pull" command without docker.

I went to download docker from their site and upon attempting installation I was greeted with a message saying I needed an enterprise/pro edition of windows 10.

How do I get around this and use [the get started guide.](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a docker product called [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) which advertises support for older versions of windows. It requires a 64-bit version of Windows 7 or better.